# How to enumerate SCSS classes

Tags: sass

How can I comma-separate classes in Sass (scss) without repeating the CSS itself in the compiled code?

I have:

```
@for $i from 1 through ($maxcolumns){
  .col#{$i}{
    //code for all columns
  }
}
```

which generates

```
.col1{
  //code
}
.col2{
  //code
}
```

but I prefer

```
.col1, .col2, ...{
  //code
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can't when using a loop to generate selectors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's what @extend is for:

```
%commonStyles {
    border: 1px solid;
}

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .col#{$i}{
    @extend %commonStyles;
  }
}
```

Generates:

```
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4, .col5 {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```